# What might be causing our opportunities to change record type?

Tags: opportunity, record-type

We use several opportunity record types. Recently we have the system change a few of the record types from one to another, possibly as a result of a workflow field update (just guessing on that). There does not seem to be any rhyme or reason as to what is triggering this, so I am trying figure out what the culprit might possibly be, so I can test.

Comment: Check what triggers you have working on oppyts

Comment: What does the Stage History say? Maybe the time or user who changed it will help you narrow it down

Answer (score 1):

Since recordtypeId is a field on the Opportunity object, it is potentially updateable through any means wherein an SObject's fields are changeable. These include:

- Workflow Field Updates
- Approval process field updates
- Apex triggers/classes including VF controllers & scheduled batch processes
- Custom button onclick Javascript
- SFDC Dataloader or its 3rd party equivalents
- REST/SOAP API clients calling your Salesforce org
- Salesforce1 mobile apps
- and some I probably forgot

For workflow Field Updates - you can easily see if they exist by going to Setup | Create | Workflow.

By examining Field History and Stage History on the Opportunity (as Eric suggests)  - presuming you are showing these related lists, you could gain insight into the process that might be changing the recordTypeId.  If that does not work, you could create a workflow to email yourself whenever a recordtypeId changes from x to y and that could help trace the cause (by identifying the user/datetime, and other oppo fields)

### UPDATE (2024-01)

If you have Lead assignment rules running in the transaction, be sure to check the value of `Setup > Lead Settings > Behavior used when applying assignment rules to manually-created records`

So, the recordType you think you're explicitly assigning (in the API call, before create Flow, before insert trigger, etc) *can be altered simply by running Lead Assignment rules if the setting is as shown in the figure.*

[image]

Comment: The one you forgot is the most likely culprit. Changing ownership changes the record type to the default for that user.

Comment: really? I did not know this - note https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hEdxAAE, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm&language=en_US,